Getting 20001 Error: Invalid Message SID When Trying to Download Media from Twilio WhatsApp Conversation API
I am integrating Twilio WhatsApp with the Twilio Conversation API in my ASP.NET Core 8 application. I’m able to retrieve messages and media details, but when I try to download media using the generated URL, I get the following error:
<TwilioResponse>
  <RestException>
    <Code>20001</Code>
    <Message>Invalid message sid: IMe6a9630de0df4c5c90f3b74a844a5d3c</Message>
    <MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20001</MoreInfo>
    <Status>400</Status>
  </RestException>
</TwilioResponse>

Problem:
The error message suggests that the message.Sid is invalid when I try to download media from Twilio. I have verified that I am using the correct message.Sid and mediaSid as provided in the response, yet I am still unable to retrieve the media.
**
Steps I've Taken:**
Double-checked the message.Sid and mediaSid to ensure they are correct.
Ensured my Twilio Account SID and Auth Token are set up correctly for authentication.
Used the media SID in the download URL as per the documentation.
Question:
Can anyone help explain why I am receiving the 20001 error, and what I can do to successfully download media from Twilio’s API in my WhatsApp integration?

The error description says "One or more parameters you sent the REST API were not recognized and were ignored.". Can you add your request you are sending with all parameters (expect auth token)?
Are you using the right function as instructed in the docs?

Interesting. I'm just getting the exact same error.

I had this issue in a Spring Boot / Kotlin service. It turned out I was hitting the incorrect endpoint to retrieve the media by message ID.
Instead, I needed to hit a conversations-specific endpoint:
GET /Services/{Chat Service SID}/Media/{Media SID}

It's detailed here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/media-resource#retrieve-a-media-resource
After wiring that up correctly, I finally started to get some useful information back, including a signed URL to the media resource itself.
{
    "sid": "MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "service_sid": "ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "date_created": "2024-11-19T23:00:18.795324Z",
    "date_upload_updated": "2024-11-19T23:00:18.799154Z",
    "date_updated": "2024-11-19T23:00:18.795324Z",
    "links": {
        "content": "/v1/Services/ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Media/MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Content",
        "content_direct_temporary": "https://media.us1.twilio.com/MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?Expires=1732060217&Signature=blahblahblah"
    },
    "size": 55795,
    "content_type": "image/jpeg",
    "filename": "123_1.jpeg",
    "author": null,
    "category": "media",
    "message_sid": "IMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "channel_sid": "CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "url": "/v1/Services/ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Media/MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "is_multipart_upstream": false
}

Hopefully that's easily enough to set up in your .NET project.
